# Select resource in Kubernetes by one of multiple label values

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster where a resource is available in multiple types.

They are labeled `r_Type=r1`, `r_Type=r2`, and so on.

I need to start a pod that can run on a number of those types. For just one type, the corresponding YAML file would be simple:

```yaml
nodeSelector:
    r_Type: r1
```

How do I write that if the pod can run on multiple of these resources? I see in the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#set-based-requirement) on labels that there is an 'in' set notation. But how do I write it? The following code does not look right:

```yaml
nodeSelector:
    r_Type in (r1, r2)
```

That does not seem like valid YAML.

Can someone provide an example of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the set syntax in a `nodeSelector`; that field is a simple `key: value` map:

```
$ kubectl explain pod.spec.nodeSelector
KIND:     Pod
VERSION:  v1

FIELD:    nodeSelector <map[string]string>

DESCRIPTION:
     NodeSelector is a selector which must be true for the pod to fit on a node.
     Selector which must match a node's labels for the pod to be scheduled on
     that node. More info:
     https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/
```

The expression `map[string]string` is a Go type expression, and it means the value is a map of string keys to string values.

If you read through "[Assigning Pods to Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)", you'll note that there are alternatives to `nodeSelector` that have more expressive syntax. For example, the `nodeAffinity` field supports [`matchExpressions`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#resources-that-support-set-based-requirements), which do support set-based requirements:

```
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinitiy:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: r_Type
            operator: In
            values:
            - r1
            - r2
```

See also `kubectl explain`:

```
$ kubectl explain pod.spec.affinity.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms.matchExpressions
KIND:     Pod
VERSION:  v1

RESOURCE: matchExpressions <[]Object>

DESCRIPTION:
     A list of node selector requirements by node's labels.

     A node selector requirement is a selector that contains values, a key, and
     an operator that relates the key and values.

FIELDS:
   key  <string> -required-
     The label key that the selector applies to.

   operator     <string> -required-
     Represents a key's relationship to a set of values. Valid operators are In,
     NotIn, Exists, DoesNotExist. Gt, and Lt.

     Possible enum values:
     - `"DoesNotExist"`
     - `"Exists"`
     - `"Gt"`
     - `"In"`
     - `"Lt"`
     - `"NotIn"`

   values       <[]string>
     An array of string values. If the operator is In or NotIn, the values array
     must be non-empty. If the operator is Exists or DoesNotExist, the values
     array must be empty. If the operator is Gt or Lt, the values array must
     have a single element, which will be interpreted as an integer. This array
     is replaced during a strategic merge patch.
```